# transform csv file using awk script

Tags: bash, awk

I have csv file as below:

```
C1, C2,   C3,Cv1,Cv2,Cv3,Cv4 ...  this one can be have longer column
x1, x2 ,x3.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4
x1, x2, x3.2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4
x1, x2, x3.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4
```

i would like to transform this csv file to as below:

```
C1,C2,   C3,CTEXT,XVALUE
x1, x2, x3.1, Cv1 , 1.1
x1, x2, x3.1, Cv2 , 1.2
x1, x2, x3.1, Cv3 , 1.3
x1, x2, x3.1, Cv4 , 1.4
x1, x2, x3.2, Cv1 , 2.1
x1, x2, x3.2, Cv2 , 2.2
x1, x2, x3.2, Cv3 , 2.3
x1, x2, x3.2, Cv4 , 2.4
x1, x2, x3.3, Cv1 , 3.1
x1,x2,x3.3, Cv2 , 3.2
x1,x2,x3.3, Cv3 , 3.3
x1,x2,x3.3, Cv4 , 3.4
```

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ if (NR==1)
{ print $1,$2,$3, "CTEXT","XVALUE"
  i=4; while (i < NF) {
   a[i]=$i; i=i+1
  }
  am=NF; next
}
i=4 ; while (i < am) {
  if (i > NF) {print "record "NR" insufficient value" >/dev/stderr
  break}
  print $1,$2,$3,a[i],$i
  i=i+1
  }
if (am <NF) print "record "NR" too many values for text" >/dev/stderr
}' input.csv
```

When i run the script, it shows error :

awk: syntax error near line 2
awk: bailing out near line 2

---

Edit by Ed Morton - I just ran the script through a beautifier (`gawk -o- '...'`) so it's much easier to read/understand:

```
{
    if (NR == 1) {
        print $1, $2, $3, "CTEXT", "XVALUE"
        i = 4
        while (i < NF) {
            a[i] = $i
            i = i + 1
        }
        am = NF
        next
    }
    i = 4
    while (i < am) {
        if (i > NF) {
            print("record " NR " insufficient value") > (/dev/) stderr
            break
        }
        print $1, $2, $3, a[i], $i
        i = i + 1
    }
    if (am < NF) {
        print("record " NR " too many values for text") > (/dev/) stderr
    }
}
```

Comment: @Amadan Pivot is not the same as transpose.

Comment: @Barmar: True. My bad. I didn't notice the data, taking the title as correct.

Comment: that looks like an old-awk error message. try `nawk`, or `gawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. (Edit your Q to show output of `uname -srv`). Good luck.

Comment: Please pick a common style of formatting code and use that for your scripts. What you have right now with multiple statements on some lines and haphazard indenting makes your script unnecessarily difficult to understand. Also - awk supports `for` loops so you can write statements like `for (i=4; i<NF; i++) { foo }` instead of `i=4; while (i<NF) { foo; i = i + 1 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you switch your Solaris awk to gawk or nawk, there still
remain some problems. Would you please try the following:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
NR==1 {
    print $1,$2,$3, "CTEXT","XVALUE"
    for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) a[i]=$i
    am=NF; next
}
{
    if (am < NF) {
        print "record "NR" too many values for text" > "/dev/stderr"
        next
    }
    for (i = 4; i <= am; i++) {
        if (i > NF) {
            print "record "NR" insufficient value" > "/dev/stderr"
            break
        }
        print $1,$2,$3,a[i],$i
    }
}' input.csv
```

- You need to increment `i` up to `NR` or `am` (not < but <=).
- Enclose `/dev/stderr` with quotes.
- Better to use `for` loop rather than `while`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @wina If you mean the message `awk: syntax error near line 2 awk: bailing out near line 2` by the `same error`, you at first need to change to other `awk` as @shellter comments. My code above does not solve the error itself.

Comment: @wina Good to know its working. BTW it is amazing you were almost close to the right answer despite you could not run it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} 
           NR==1 {n=split($0,h); 
                  print $1,$2,$3,"CTEXT","XVALUE"; 
                  next} 
           n!=NF {print n<NF?"too many":"not enough"; 
                  exit} 
                 {for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$3,h[i],$i}' file

C1,C2,C3,CTEXT,XVALUE
x1,x2,x3.1,Cv1,1.1
x1,x2,x3.1,Cv2,1.2
x1,x2,x3.1,Cv3,1.3
x1,x2,x3.1,Cv4,1.4
x1,x2,x3.2,Cv1,2.1
x1,x2,x3.2,Cv2,2.2
x1,x2,x3.2,Cv3,2.3
x1,x2,x3.2,Cv4,2.4
x1,x2,x3.3,Cv1,3.1
x1,x2,x3.3,Cv2,3.2
x1,x2,x3.3,Cv3,3.3
x1,x2,x3.3,Cv4,3.4
```